# How can I show my data on my homepage in sails?

Tags: express, sails.js, ejs

I want to be able to show my posts on a list on the home.ejs like so.

```
<% post.forEach(function(post)  { %>
        <a href="/post/show/<%=post.id%>" style="color: inherit;">
        <h4><%= post.post_title%></h4>
        <p ><%= post.post_description%></p>
        <p><%= post.post_category%></p>
    </a>
    <% }); %>
```

Controller code:

```
index: function (req, res, next) {
Post.find( function foundPost(err, post) {
  if (err) return next(err);

  res.view({
    post: post
  });
});
```

},

How can I access them. I get a post not defined error. They work on my post/index

Comment: Please show controller code where you are calling `res.view` or similar method.

Comment: @Sangharsh in my show I have res.view({ post:post});

Comment: Did you check `post` in controller just before calling `res.view`? Is it empty or undefined by any chance?

Comment: @Sangharsh show: function (req, res, next) {
    Post.findOne( req.param('id'), function foundPost(err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!post) return next();
      res.view({
        post: post
      });
    });
  },

Comment: `findOne` returns a single object. You are calling `.forEach` in EJS. Something is wrong here.

Comment: @Sangharsh sorry wrong controller.. updated the post

Comment: It should be `Post.find({}, callback)`, not `Post.find(callback)`.

Comment: it works in my post view just not in my home view. That will fix the problem?

Comment: Please see documentation of `find`. It says `Something.find(criteria).exec(function (err, records) { ... });` http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find